# What is the table for default report source code?

Tags: abap

In SAP there is a table where you can write the "default report source code", so that every time you create a new report, the default/initial source code of said report will be whatever you entered in that table.

I have used this table in the past, but unfortunately I did not write down the name, and I can't seem to find it on the internet right now.

Does anybody know the table name by any chance?

Comment: I don't think such a thing ever existed. Maybe you are mixing it up with the templates (Ctrl + F6 while in ABAP-Editor)?

Comment: No, I am 100% sure it was a table. And you wouldn't need to manually "import" it like a template, it would automatically be the default for any *new* report

Comment: @Jagger as far as I remember the table which holds the ABAP code, exists only in the DB, not in the repository (SE11). It is only possible to read it with native SQL.

Comment: @JózsefSzikszai the table I mean definetly was a regular table, I edited it using the SM30

Comment: I have put some effort and debugged the creation of a program in SE38 with breakpoint on statement SELECT. What your are looking for seems to be in the table `TSE05` under the key `APP_OBJ = 'ADDM' KEYWORD = 'REPORT'`. If it is what you are looking for I will post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @Jagger you are a godsend, exactly what I was looking for! In addition: `KEYWORD = 'REPORT+T'` is for creating a report with top include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are looking for seems to be in the table `TSE05` under the key `APP_OBJ = 'ADDM' KEYWORD = 'REPORT'`.

Comment: In addition: `KEYWORD = 'REPORT+T'` is used when creating a report with top include

Answer (score 2):

For auto-populating the SE38 report source you should add the records `*1` to TSE05 table.

TSE05 keyword column stores pattern name for using via Pattern tool in SE38 or other source editor

[image]

To edit the header/pattern for a particular keyword one should maintain lines in that table.

To make it auto-populated at object creation the table must have lines with `KEYWORD`

- `*F` for Subroutines
- `*M` for Modules
- `*1` for executable programs 
  etc.

Sample:

```
  APP_OBJ KEYWORD POS LINE
  ABAP        *F    1   *----------------------------------------------------------------------*
  ABAP        *F    2   *       FORM .......
  ABAP        *F    3   *----------------------------------------------------------------------*
  ABAP        *F    4   *       text
  ABAP        *F    5   *----------------------------------------------------------------------*
  ABAP        *F    6   *  -->  p1        text
  ABAP        *F    7   *  <--  p2        text
  ABAP        *F    8   *----------------------------------------------------------------------*
```