# Which variables can be used in TSE05 templates?

Tags: abap

I am using TSE05 to create a template for new ABAP Reports (my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72346988/what-is-the-table-for-default-report-source-code/) for reference).

In there I can use variables/placeholders like `$PROG` for the report name or `$TOP` for the name of the top include.

Is there a complete list of variables/placeholders which I can use inside those templates? Those two are the only ones I have found so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables are hard-coded in standard program `SAPLSEUR` form `FETCH_TEMPLATE`.

The template lines are read from TSE05

```
SELECT line FROM tse05 INTO TABLE temptab
  WHERE app_obj = 'ADDM'
    AND keyword = tse05key
ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY.
```

(here tse05key can be `REPORT`, `INCLUDE` etc.. based on the object type you're creating)

Then it looks for some hard-coded placeholders from TSE05 template lines, and replaces them with the correct information

```
LOOP AT temptab ASSIGNING <line>.
  REPLACE '$PROG' IN <line>      WITH progname.  "ignoriert spaces
  REPLACE '$TOP'  WITH inclname  INTO <line>.
  REPLACE '$POOL' WITH pool      INTO <line>.
  REPLACE '$USER' WITH space     INTO <line>.
  REPLACE '$DATE' WITH space     INTO <line>.
  REPLACE '$O01'  WITH oinclname INTO <line>.
  REPLACE '$I01'  WITH iinclname INTO <line>.
  REPLACE '$F01'  WITH finclname INTO <line>.
ENDLOOP.
```

This form is called by another form `INSERT_PROGRAM` in program `SAPLSEDTATTR` when creating a source so at the end those are the only variables available

Comment: Thank you so much! But the `$USER` and `$DATE` placeholders are not working:
https://imgur.com/a/W6eNFXt

Why does it replace them with space?

Comment: app object `ADDM` is the standard key used when creating a new report. In this case`$USER` and `$DATE` are not available. You can use those variables with other app objects. Please consider that changing entries with `ADDM` keys is considered a standard modification and any change will be reset in future upgrades. (Custom namespace for TSE05 is U*)